# How to create a dictionary with lists as values out of a csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file with 19 columns and want to make it as a dictionary that the first 2 columns be the key (maybe a tuple or just merge them as one string), and then all other 17 columns be a list as values. the excel file looks like this: [image of the cvs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWekA.png)

I want to have a dictionary like this :

```
d1 = { "A , 222" : [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}  
d2={"B, 223" : [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]}
d3 = {....}

....
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

```
from csv import reader

d = {}
with open('infile.csv', newline='') as f:
    r = reader(f)
    for row in r:
        if not row:
            continue # Handles blank rows
        key1, key2, *value = row
        d[(key1, key2)] = value
```

Edit:

The line `key1, key2, *value = row` will only work in Python 3.  If that feature is not available to you, you can use

```
key1, key2 = row[:2]
value = row[2:]
```

Comment: This answer really shows how to use modules well. Good Job!

Comment: `key1, key2, *value = row` should only work on `Python 3.x`.

Comment: @FrankAK That's a good point, I'll add a line that can work for older versions.

Comment: in that case remove `newline=""` from the open statement :) (it's not useful anyway when opening a file for _reading_)

Comment: your `(key1, key2) = value` should covert to string instead of tuple!

Comment: @FrankAK "maybe a tuple or just merge them as one string" doesn't seem like the asker has a real preference.

Comment: Maybe! But I guess he do not how to covert a tuple to a string )!(

Answer (score 0):

Are you means this?

```
res = {}
with open(fileName.csv, "r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for line in text[1:]:
        part = line.strip().split(",")
        key  = ",".join(part[:2])
        value = [int(i) for i in part[2:]]
        res[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using csv.reader you can do that like:

#### Code:

```
as_dict = {'{}, {}'.format(*row[:2]): row[2:] for row in reader if row}
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = StringIO(''.join('\n'.join(x.strip() for x in u"""
    A,222,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  
    B,223,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
    """.split('\n')[1:-1])))

reader = csv.reader(data)
as_dict = {'{}, {}'.format(*row[:2]): row[2:] for row in reader if row}
print(as_dict)
```

#### Results:

```
{
    'A, 222': ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
    'B, 223': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
}
```